# How to setup Fastlane (or Transifex) to deal with languages in Android application?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, transifex

I have an open source Android application translated by community with Transifex (with full integration with GitHub). I use it both for Android app resources and Play Store metadata. Problem is that Android resources use language-only codes, like `fr`, `en`, `de`. But Play Store requires language-country codes like `fr_FR`, `en_US`, `de_DE`. I can not find any options in Transifex settings or Fastlane settings to configure aliases. Transifex allows configuring language mapping but only for project, not for specific path. Fastlane does not have any language settings at all. Does anybody have any ideas?